# Cleanest way for conditional code instantiation in C++ template

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to get the following C++ code running:

```
#include <cmath>

template<typename T, bool> class ConditionalData {
};

template <typename T> class ConditionalData<T, false> {
};

template <typename T> class ConditionalData<T, true> {
private:
    T data;
public:
    void setData(T _data) { data = _data; }
};


template<bool hasdata> class A {
public:
    A() {
        ConditionalData<double,hasdata> data;
        if (hasdata) {
            data.setData(sin(cos(123.4)));
        }
    }
};


int main(int argNum, const char**argData) {
    A<false> test1;
    A<true> test2;
    return 0;
}
```

Essentially, I want to implement a templated class A in which certain operations are executed depending on the template parameter. These operations need local variables, which I only want to be allocated if needed. The problem that I'm having here is that the body of the

```
if (hasdata) {
    data.setData(3);
}
```

condition is also instantiated for hasdata=false, which does not compile (using g++ 5.2). Any ideas how to get this done in the cleanest way without splitting the body of A::A() into pieces?

The source code above is a minimal non-working example. The real implementation for A::A() is relatively long, with the parts dependent on "hasdata" being distributed evenly over the code. Also, the "typename T" for which the class A will be used is a relatively complex class with heavy-weight constructors/destructors, so I want the instances of T to only be allocated when hasdata=true. Finally, in the data.setData(...) calls, there can be complex computations in the "...", which should only be performed if needed.

Comment: "relatively long, with the parts dependent on "hasdata" being distributed evenly over the code". Then perhaps rethink your attitude towards promoting such parts to separate functions.

Comment: The thing is that separate functions would actually make the code a lot harder to read. Each of the separate functions would only ever called once, and there is an accompanying paper in which the function is explained as a block (as it is easier to read in this way).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you can afford for [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14), you can express the conditional branches as generic lambdas. The benefit is that they capture surrounding variables and the solution doesn't require extra member functions.

```
template <bool> struct tag {};

template <typename T, typename F>
auto static_if(tag<true>, T t, F f) { return t; }

template <typename T, typename F>
auto static_if(tag<false>, T t, F f) { return f; }

template <bool B, typename T, typename F>
auto static_if(T t, F f) { return static_if(tag<B>{}, t, f); }

template <bool B, typename T>
auto static_if(T t) { return static_if(tag<B>{}, t, [](auto&&...){}); }

// ...

ConditionalData<int, hasdata> data;        
static_if<hasdata>([&](auto& d)
{
    d.setData(3);
})(data);
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ad04c7917ee7d177)

In [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) you can just say:

```
if constexpr (hasdata)
{
    data.setData(3);
}
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d43ecd2a34447ac3)

Comment: This! Lambdas are a very nice way of achieving low-overhead lazy computations while retaining the logical in-place. I would maybe provide a specialized `conditionally_invoke_on` method to wrap the `static_if` invocation: `conditionally_invoke_on(data, [&](....) {});` is more specialized but avoids this weird "data is passed at the end" syntax and the repetition of the `hasdata` bit which can be deduced by taking `data` in argument. You can rip it off from [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e05b63b491b0ec17) if you wish.

Answer (score 7):

This is a common pattern, so there's actually a paper to add [`constexpr_if`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0128r0.html) to C++. If that makes it in to future versions, it would allow you to keep your code pretty much as-is.

```
template<bool hasdata> class A {
public:
    A() {
        ConditionalData<int,hasdata> data;
        constexpr_if (hasdata) {
        //^^^^^^^^^^ instead of plain if
            data.setData(3);
        }
    }
};
```

For now, you'll need to make do with one of the other answers.

---

Edit: This was added to C++17 and called `if constexpr`

Comment: I wonder why they didn't say `static if`` (avoiding any new keywords) or `static_if` (in the vein of `static_assert`)...

Comment: @Deduplicator beats me. I guess the single token is to ease parsing. It used to be called `static_if`, but they changed it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: and as demonstrated by Piotr (currently below), it's easy enough to do with the existing facilities, and could conceivably be provided by a library (taking a lambda) rather than a language facility.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yeah, it's pretty ugly. I think it's a good issue to address, but preferably with nicer syntax. Not sure what that syntax should be though.

Comment: @TartanLlama: Me neither.

Comment: Is this in C++1z? or the version after it? (BTW what is the name of the version after 1z?)

Comment: @BryanChen This is a proposal which has not been accepted as of yet, but the consensus is that it's a useful thing to work out. I'm not on the standards committee, so take that with a grain of salt.

Comment: I think this is in C++17, as `if constexpr (...) { ... }`

Answer (score 5):

First of all, you don't require 3 versions of `class ConditionalData`, because `bool` can be either `true` or `false`. So let me simplify it as following:

```
template<typename T, bool = false> class ConditionalData {
};                 //^^^^^^^^^^^^

template <typename T> class ConditionalData<T, true> {
private:
    T data;
public:
    void setData(T _data) { data = _data; }
};
```

Secondly, to answer your question: Whichever members are falling for `false` category, just overload them outside the `class` body as following:

```
template<bool hasdata> class A { 
public:
    A() {
        ConditionalData<int,hasdata> data;
        if (hasdata) {
            data.setData(3);
        }
    }   
};

template<> A<false>::A() {}  // Does nothing for `false` condition
```

Comment: Thanks for your note on the non-necessity of the three versions. Having two specializations for the A constructor is a bit problematic, though, as written in the question post, its *actual* code (not the example code above) is actually quite long (~200 lines), and only a small fraction is dependent on "hasData". That would mean replicating ~190 lines.

Comment: @DCTLib, that can be fixed trivially. Move the specific code related to `hasData` to some function, e.g. `hasDataRelated()` and then overload only that function as I have done for `A()`. Repeat such procedure for all the `bool` specific code.

Comment: That's a nice idea. Thanks for suggesting it.

Answer (score 4):

you can define `setData` for both branches, empty one for `false` condition:

```
template<typename T, bool> class ConditionalData {
};

template <typename T> class ConditionalData<T, false> {
    void setData(T _data) {}
};

template <typename T> class ConditionalData<T, true> {
private:
    T data;
public:
    void setData(T _data) { data = _data; }
};

template<bool hasdata> class A {
public:
    A() {
        ConditionalData<int,hasdata> data;
        data.setData(3);
    }
};
```

Comment: Though technically this approach is correct, there is a problem here. If some substantial code is being run in the constructor of `data` (which is not present in the example code), then creating an object `data` just do nothing in `setData()` would be an overkill. Better approach is to overload `A<false>::A()` and keep it empty. Look at [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34589766/514235).

Comment: @iammilind it's definitely not overkill as these empty members and empty specializations will be removed by the compiler.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The thing is that the above code is actually a simplication of what happens in reality. There can be calls such as "data.setData(...complex_calculation...)" and I don't want the calculation to take place if not needed.

Comment: @bolov, I don't think the compiler optimization is guaranteed. e.g. If you put a debug/print statement inside the constructor of `ConditionalData`, it's always going to instantiate the constructor and create the object `data` and then do nothing in `setData()`.

Comment: @iammilind why would you put a `print` in the constructor of `ConditionalData<false>` ?

Answer (score 3):

If you cannot(/don't want to) change `ConditionalData`, you may create 2 methods instead:

```
template<typename T>
void SetData(ConditionalData<T, false>& , const T& ) {/* Nothing */}

template<typename T>
void SetData(ConditionalData<T, true>& c, const T& value) { c.setData(value); }
```

and then

```
A() {
    ConditionalData<int, hasdata> data;
    SetData(data, 3);
}
```

For more complex cases

```
template<typename T>
void A_impl_part1(ConditionalData<T, false>&) {/* Nothing */}

template<typename T>
void A_impl_part1(ConditionalData<T, true>& c) { c.setData(3); }
```

and then

```
A() {
    ConditionalData<int, hasdata> data;
    A_impl_part1(data);
    // common part
    // A_impl_part2(data); // and so on
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The thing is that the above code is actually a simplification of what happens in reality. There can be calls such as "data.setData(...complex_calculation...)" and I don't want the calculation to take place if not needed.

Comment: @DCTLib: add example for non-trivial case.

Comment: @DCTLib You are adding constraints that are not visible in the question, so please update your question.

Comment: @WernerHenze Indeed - I forgot to list that in the original post. I've updated it accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the preprocessor to 'generate' each variation of your class as template specializations.

First, the 'template' header we will generate the specializations from:

```
ATemplate.h
//no include guards to allow multiple inclusion
template<>
class A<A_HAS_DATA>
{
public:
    A()
    {
#if A_HAS_DATA
        double data;
        if (hasdata) {
            data = sin(cos(123.4));
        }
#endif
    }
}
```

Then we actually generate each specialization to obtain a normal header to use in your code:

```
A.h
#pragma once

template<bool hasdata>
class A;

//Generate specialization for hasdata = true
#define A_HAS_DATA 1
#include "ATemplate.h"
#undef A_HAS_DATA
//(undef avoids redefinition warning)
//Generate specialization for hasdata = false
#define A_HAS_DATA 0
#include "ATemplate.h"
#undef A_HAS_DATA
```

Essentially, instead of manually writing each specialization for each possible case (given that you might have multiple such settings to include/exclude stuff), we use preprocessor to generate each variant by including a header multiple times, each time with a different value for preprocessor define(s) to get different result.

Prefer to use normal template approaches when they work, but if the amount of manual code duplication (to define all the possible variants) grows too high, this approach can work (as you can specify everything 'inline' akin what static if would do if we had one)

Comment: -1: C++ has been trying to move away from the preprocessor for years. There is no reason to use it if the language supports an alternative.

Comment: Exactly, an alternative. For the example in the question pure templates probably work fine, but once you go further (more flags, more bits and pieces to conditionally include), you have to reevaluate the advantages and disadvantages of both approaches against each other. Having your code readable and not having to repeat yourself all over the place are reasons to use this solution when the template alternative shows its inability to scale.

Comment: @isanae macros and the preprocessor are not evil. Just because there are alternatives does not make this solution somehow worse.

Comment: @Alice Yes, I believe it does. It doesn't make it invalid, but it does make it worse.

Comment: @isanae Okay. You are free to have a opinion, no matter how wrong it is. But that doesn't mean your statement `There is no reason to use it if the language supports an alternative.` has any validity.